# how get elements in group? Python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I need to get the href of each element in a list, how can i do this? on bs4

```
<div class="group">

<a href="link1" target="_blank" rel="rel" class="class">
    <h1>"test"</h1>
</a>
    <a href="link2" target="_blank" rel="rel" class="class">
        <h1>"test2"</h1>
    </a>
<a href="link3" target="_blank" rel="rel" class="class">
    <h1>"test3"</h1>
</a>            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the `<div>` with class group and iterate over its `<a>` for example with `css selectors` and `list comprehension`:

```
[x['href'] for x in soup.select('div.group a')]
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="group">
<a href="link1" target="_blank" rel="rel" class="class">
    <h1>"test"</h1>
</a>
    <a href="link2" target="_blank" rel="rel" class="class">
        <h1>"test2"</h1>
    </a>
<a href="link3" target="_blank" rel="rel" class="class">
    <h1>"test3"</h1>
</a>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

[x['href'] for x in soup.select('div.group a')]
```

#### Output

```
['link1', 'link2', 'link3']
```